# Using C# remove unnecessary “TABLE_NAME” from Excel worksheets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Can anyone tell me, I am going to upload excel file, this file has unnecessary table like   "_xlnm#Print_Titles" that I need to remove or delete that field. This a my method. But it is does not work for remove or delete.

```
static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
{
    OleDbConnection con = null;
    DataTable dt = null;

    con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();

    dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);           

    if ((dt == null) )
    {
        return null;
    }

    String[] excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];

    int i = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        if ((excelSheetNames[i].Contains("_xlnm#Print_Titles") || (excelSheetNames[i].Contains("Print_Titles"))))
        {
            if (true)
            {
                row.Table.Rows.Remove(row);
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

    return excelSheetNames;
}
```

Comment: Removing items from a list that you're enumerating is a bad idea. (do not remove items in a foreach loop). I suggest a do while loop for that task. 

also what's your reasoning behind `if(true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing items in the foreach loop, we'll find them and add them to a list, then we'll go through that list and remove them from your data table.

```
static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = null;
        DataTable dt = null;

        con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

        if ((dt == null))
        {
            return null;
        }

        String[] excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];

        var rowsToRemove = new List<DataRow>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row = dt.Rows[i];
            excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            if ((excelSheetNames[i].Contains("_xlnm#Print_Titles") || (excelSheetNames[i].Contains("Print_Titles"))))
            {
                   rowsToRemove.Add(dt.Rows[i]);
            }

            i++;
        }

        foreach (var dataRow in rowsToRemove)
        {
            dt.Rows.Remove(dataRow);
        }

        return excelSheetNames;
    }
```

Comment: This method return following values now

[0]"'Bob-169$'"
[1] null
[2] "Annl"
[3] null
[4] Print_Titles

Comment: I remove bottom area duplicate i++; But still not remove Print_Titles. Why was that?

Comment: But still not remove Print_Titles. Are there any way to remove remove Print_Titles?

Comment: I debugged code,  dt has already deleted Print_Titles but return excelSheetNames; method still remain Print_Titles. Why was that?

Answer (score 0):

Those _xlnm and "$" are sheets that, turns out, shouldn't be normally accessed by the users.

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Ignore them
2. Drop them

The former is highly recommended.

To do this you need to use the following code:

```
if (!dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase") && !dt.Rows[i]["Table_Name"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
{
}
```

You can either use `.Contains()` and/or `.EndsWith()` to ***filter*** out those sheets.